Is there a way to tell the difference between a CofE church and a Roman Catholic one?
Are there any physical or aesthetic differences in a church's name (saint dedication), architecture, signage etc that identify it at CofE or Roman Catholic from the outside?
(After years of being deaf and blind in the wilderness, I am re-discovering my Anglican faith.  I travel the length and breadth of the UK for work, and want to attend church on my travels but I would prefer to know if it is CofE or RC before hand)

Signs outside Roman Catholic churches are more likely to say "Catholic Church".  Old buildings are more likely to be Church of England. You could also check on the name of the diocese or archdiocese.  But in any case a quick search on the internet should clarify matters.

A Church NearYou.com. is the Church of England's official church finder tool.

I wuld have thught, statistically, that Catholic churches would be in a minority in the UK. They had to build new ones from the nineteeth century onwards..

If you are a bat expert then you may be able to detect the difference between Protestant bats and Catholic ones and tell that way. Probably not terribly practical but there we are. https://www.deseret.com/1996/11/19/19277780/even-ireland-s-bats-split-on-religious-lines/

Since you are both deaf and blind, then would I be correct in thinking that the only way you could determine if a church was RC or CofE would be to ask someone? Perhaps the CofE has a UK register of churches in Brail they could send to you in the post?

@Lesley, I think it was a metaphor for being in a spiritual wilderness.

@Lesley This was a practical question of identifying buildings. The number of worshippers has no impact on the number of buildings, and the designated Catholic ones are still likely to have newer brickwork.

@StephenDisraeli - My problem is that I have a tendency to take things literally. Metaphors are mostly wasted on me. Sometimes I forget that CSE is a serious academic site. Am I forgiven?

@Leslie If one was, literally, deaf and blind, perhaps one could smell the place for incense. But it is not infallible as some Hgh Church Angicans have incense too.

I have taken the liberty of contacting the Church of England to ask if they have a register of U.K. churches printed in Brail.
I can only assume that someone will be able to read this message  and inform you of what it says.  Here is the link I used, which also gives an address and a phone number:
https://www.churchofengland.org/terms-and-conditions/contact-us
Phone: +44(0)20 7898 1000
Address:
Church of England National Office,
Great Smith Street,
London SW1P 3AZ.

@Heddy - Thanks for your vote and I hope you understand I wasn't trying to be funny when I left you that link. I've known people who are deaf mute, but never someone both deaf and blind (literally). I once was spiritually deaf and blind but the good Lord was gracious enough to unstop my ears, open my eyes and soften my heart to turn to Him.

Pretty much all churches have signs outside that identify them. Catholic churches are almost always going to say "Catholic" somewhere on the sign. Most Anglican churches will say "Anglican" or "Church of England"; if it doesn't have any indication of denomination then it's probably Anglican as well, just because the vast majority of traditional-looking churches in England are Anglican. If the church is the only traditional-looking church in a village then it is almost certainly Anglican. 99% of the time this will solve your problem.
There is very little in terms of style or decoration that gives away the distinction without signage, because many Anglican churches were "converted" from Catholic ones at the time of the Reformation. For example, older Anglican may well have Latin inscriptions, even though Latin is no longer used in the Anglican church. Confessionals are a fairly solid sign of a Catholic church, especially if they are in use. A large crucifix or "stations of the cross" will generally indicate Catholic, but not invariably in older churches.
You may find other indication near the literature display, or the books in the pews. You will find events and organisations advertised that are identified as "Church of England" or "Catholic".
